# tkinter GUI errors with class declaration and global name "parent" not defined?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, indentation

this is the current code i have that i edited and tried to get working, but still doesnt work :/ debugging help would be awesome :) it gives errors with the variables "self" and "parent" not being defined in the mainWindow class, as well as an error with the line "class mainWindow". not entirely sure what they both mean or how to fix

```
import sys, Tkinter
sys.modules['tkinter'] = Tkinter
import Pmw

class Print:

    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text

    def __call__(self):
        print self.text

class mainWindow:

    def __init__(self,parent,balloon):
        self.balloon = Pmw.Balloon(parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.menuBar = menuBar
        self.mainPart = mainPart
        self.buttonBox = buttonBox

    def Quit():
        root.destroy()

    menuBar = Pmw.MenuBar(parent,hull_relief = 'raised',hull_borderwidth = 1,balloon = self.balloon)
    menuBar.pack(fill = 'x')

    menuBar.addmenu('Run Control','Calibration,Download Configuration,Number of Triggers,Data Output File,Upload Configuration,Start DAQ,Quit')
    menuBar.addcascademenu('Run Control','Calibration','View and/or change the calibration',traverseSpec = 'z',tearoff = 1)
    menuBar.addmenuitem('Calibration','command','Display the DAC calibration',command = Print('display the DAC calibration'),label = 'Display DAC Calibration')

    menuBar.addmenuitem('Calibration','command','Display the calibration mask',command = Print('display the calibration mask'),label = 'Display Calibration Mask')
    menuBar.addmenuitem('Calibration','command','Change the DAC calibration',command = Print('change the DAC calibration'),label = 'Change DAC Calibration')
    menuBar.addmenuitem('Calibration','command','Change the calibration mask',command = Print('change the calibration mask'),label = 'Change Calibration Mask')

    menuBar.addmenuitem('Run Control','command','Download a configuration',command = Print('download configuration'),label = 'Download Configuration')

    menuBar.addmenuitem('Run Control','command','Set the number of triggers',command = Print('set number of triggers'),label = 'Number of Triggers')
    menuBar.addmenuitem('Run Control','command','Change the file where the data will be sent to',command = Print('set data output file'),label = 'Data Output File')
    menuBar.addmenuitem('Run Control','command','Upload a configuration',command = Print('upload a configuration'),label = 'Upload Configuration')

    menuBar.addmenuitem('Run Control','command','Start the data aquisition',command = Print('start data aquisition'),label = 'Start DAQ')
    menuBar.addmenuitem('Run Control','separator')
    menuBar.addmenuitem('Run Control','command','Close the GUI',command = Quit,label = 'Quit')
    menuBar.addmenu('Slow Control','Voltage, Current,Temperature,DAC Settings')
    menuBar.addmenuitem('Slow Control','command','Display the voltage',command = Print('display voltage'),label = 'Voltage')
    menuBar.addmenuitem('Slow Control','command','Display the current',command = Print('display current'),label = 'Current')
    menuBar.addmenuitem('Slow Control','command','Display the temperature',command = Print('display temperature'),label = 'Temperature')
    menuBar.addmenuitem('Slow Control','command','Display the DAC settings',command = Print('display DAC settings'),label = 'DAC Settings')
    menuBar.addmenu('Graphics','Channel Map,Energy Detector,Root Output,Slow Control Time,Histograms,One Event Display')
    menuBar.addmenuitem('Graphics','command','Display the channel map',command = Print('display channel map'),label = 'Channel Map')
    menuBar.addmenuitem('Graphics','command','Display the energy detector',command = Print('display energy detector'),label = 'Energy Detector')
    menuBar.addmenuitem('Graphics','command','Display the root output',command = Print('display root output'),label = 'Root Output')
    menuBar.addmenuitem('Graphics','command','Display the slow control time',command = Print('display slow control time'),label = 'Slow Control Time')
    menuBar.addmenuitem('Graphics','command','Display various histograms',command = Print('display histograms'),label = 'Histograms')
    menuBar.addmenuitem('Graphics','command','Display the one event display',command = Print('display one event display'),label = 'One Event Display')
    menuBar.addmenu('Edit Data Base','Make Configuration Files')
    menuBar.addmenuitem('Edit Data Base','command','Make the Configuration Files',command = Print('create configuration files'),label = 'Create Configuration Files')

    mainPart = Tkinter.Label(parent,text = 'GUI',background = 'white',foreground = 'white',padx = 100,pady = 100)
    mainPart.pack(fill = 'both', expand = 1)

    buttonBox = Pmw.ButtonBox(parent)
    buttonBox.pack(fill = 'x')
    buttonBox.add('Start\nRoot', command = Print('start root'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tkinter.Tk()
    Pmw.initialise(root)
    root.title('pCT GUI')
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You should give more information (source code) on your problem with the error message.  What kind of error message do you get?  To handle indentation problems, convert all tabs to spaces.  In most cases this solves all the issues.  (At least you see them then and most likely will be able to fix them.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should post all of your code and the exact error message so I can better help but from what you posted it seems that your problems are:

```
class foo:
```

is empty. So you need it to look like

```
class foo:
    pass
```

in order to not get an error.

Parent not being defined is probably due to that fact that you never defined the variable parent so you probably want something along the lines of:

```
parent = Tkinter.Tk()
```

Comment: is that opening a new toplevel window? i put this in ad did this for self and it made the GUI work but it is opening 3 windows now... not sure why.

Comment: @user2833744 If you post your code I can answer that better, however make sure you have one parent defined and all your frames are initialized with that parent as their parameter. Initialize other widgets with the frame as their parent. If you edit your post with the code that is causing your problems I can debug it for you.

Comment: i edited the above code with my full code and wrote what errors i am getting when i run it.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument for `MenuBar` is to specify the parent window whose `MenuBar` belongs to. You get an error since you didn't define it. If `MenuBar` is a top-level widget, just link it the root :

```
root = Tk()
menuBar = Pmw.MenuBar(root,
    hull_relief = 'raised',
    hull_borderwidth = 1,
    balloon = self.balloon)
menuBar.pack(fill = 'x')

root.mainloop()
```